# Are there any 3rd party jQuery UI themes?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-theme

I'm a little tired of the jQuery UI themes.

Are there any free 3rd-party themes that look a little slicker?

Comment: You may well have discovered it already, but you can make your own pretty easily: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: http://www.danvega.org/blog/2011/6/15/Aristo-jQuery-UI-Theme

Answer (score 2):

One alternative that goes along with my personal style is **"Aristo" for jQuery UI!**

See the [Link!](http://taitems.tumblr.com/post/482577430/introducing-aristo-a-jquery-ui-theme)

See the [Demo!](http://taitems.github.com/Aristo-jQuery-UI-Theme/)

See the [GitHub!](https://github.com/taitems/Aristo-jQuery-UI-Theme)

Nonetheless, themes provided by [jQuery UI ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) were only meant to be a starting point for users to create their own theme.

Answer (score 2):

Or take the standard jquery-ui.css and nab the parts of it that apply to you e.g. if you're only using tabs then just grab all the tabs css or more if you're using multiple aspects. So for example if you're just using the tabs part take this small section from the

```
.ui-tabs { position: relative; padding: .2em; zoom: 1; } /* position: relative prevents IE scroll bug (element with position: relative inside container with overflow: auto appear as "fixed") */
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav { margin: 0; padding: .2em .2em 0; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li { list-style: none; float: left; position: relative; top: 1px; margin: 0 .2em 1px 0; border-bottom: 0 !important; padding: 0; white-space: nowrap; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a { float: left; padding: .5em 1em; text-decoration: none; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected { margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 1px; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a, .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-disabled a,     .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-processing a { cursor: text; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a, .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-collapsible .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected a { cursor: pointer; } /* first selector in group seems obsolete, but required to overcome bug in Opera applying cursor: text overall if defined elsewhere... */
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel { display: block; border-width: 0; padding: 1em 1.4em; background: none; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide { display: none !important; }
```

and then just style change as you please.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://www.michaelvanderheeren.be/?p=382

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has released something called bootstrap which will help you to neatly arrange the elements in a screen for different screen sizes adjusted automatically too ! .As you need a slicker kind of theme.[Try twitter's bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Try Wijmo. They have few good jquery ui themes.

http://wijmo.com/theming/